# Automatically activate users' timeline on login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I am using the JavaScript SDK to login in the user on my website via Facebook, requiring the `publish_actions` permission. If I am getting it right, Open Graph stories published by using `publish_actions` are only visible for users who have their timeline enabled.

Is it possible to automatically activate the users' timeline after he logged in to my application and gave me the `publish_actions` permissions. I've seen authentication dialogs around the web where applications request the `publish_actions` permission and after granting the permission and logging in, the user automatically has the new timeline enabled.

I already searched a lot, but unfortunately I could not find anything in the developer documentation about how to do that.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request the `publish_actions` permission from the user and you have the action approved by Facebook, the message you talk about will appear in the login popup. Facebook automatically adds this message in as the features are only available with the new timeline profile. There isn't a setting you need to configure to add this message in.

[image: Upgrade Message]

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the intent of **modifying** user settings, and you can't do that.

Comment: I discovered this on www.mixcloud.com
I logged in via facebook and in the auth-dialog it said something like:

"to use this app, you will be upgradet to timeline"

After granting the perms, i had the new timeline enabled in my fb-profile.

I was thinking that there must be an official way to do this, as the user is informed about the upgrade in the auth-dialog, before he grants the permissions to the app ?! (sry for the double-post)

Comment: Ah, well, I can't really test it since I've had the timeline for a few months already, but if you read in the [Permissions doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) it says: " The user-prompt for this permission will be displayed in the first screen of the Enhanced Auth Dialog and cannot be revoked as part of the authentication flow", since it's a must, facebook probably makes sure that if a user authorizes this permission he automatically switches to the timeline, if that's the case it will happen with your app as well.

Comment: Ok, thx for the info.
I already stumbled accross this description in the permissions-doc.
I only thought i was missing something, as i am already requesting for the permission in FB.login, but within my app there is no such message shown to the user in the auth-dialog. 
Maybe the reason could be that currently i am only testing with objects/actions which are not approved yet?

Comment: Well, if you are the one that is testing it, and you already have the timeline, then why would it display such a message?

Comment: I also tested it with an fb-account which has not enabled the timeline yet. Thats the reason why i was wondering...

Comment: I took a look at the code for mixcloud and it seems pretty standard: *FB.login(callbackFunction, { scope: "publish_actions,email" })*. Maybe they are using [Authenticated Referrals](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals)? Give it a try.

Comment: Still no luck after trying with Authenticated Referalls.

But i found the follwoing on http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=121359044613137:

"In order to access certain apps on Facebook, you'll need to upgrade to timeline. This will happen automatically when you choose to install the app for the first time. "

Whats not clear to me is of what type this "certain apps" should be resp. where to find more information about that...

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what's going on, I have two guesses: 1. some apps have special privileges from facebook, maybe that's what they mean by "certain apps". 2. When I added the "publish_actions" to the authenticated referalls I got this message: "Please note that the 'publish_actions' permission will only be visible to the developers and testers of your app, until your actions are approved", maybe that's the cause. Have you tried to submit actions for approval?

Comment: Well, i think i am stuck here.
I already got my actions approved, so this might not be the reason why it does not work.
Maybe you´re right and some apps have a special aggreement with FB...
Anyway, if i ever find out whats the prob, i´ll let you know